# Started W8/Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot but got scared. How can I make sure to just run Windows again like always?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a pre-installed W8 laptop, and since I had always had no trouble dual-booting Ubuntu with my older laptops, I saw no reason why I'd have trouble now. However, I see that W8 is giving Linux users a bit of trouble.

Anyway, I made an Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit DVD, booted from the DVD, installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside W8 (creating a partition for Ubuntu through the installer), and it said it completed successfully.

My laptop only boots to W8. No hint of Ubuntu. I read that turning of secure boot, running boot-repair in Ubuntu, and a few other methods might fix this, but I also read of so many users not being able to boot back into W8.

I decided I'm not cut out for this and will just keep my laptop how it is - running Windows just fine.

I'm willing to sacrifice that partitioned harddrive space, but is there going to be any issue in my foreseeable future with my laptop like this? I would delete the Ubuntu partition, but I read about some people then having trouble since the GRUB menu replaced the windows boot manager. Are there any precautionary measures I should take to ensure I have no trouble running W8?

Comment: The issues should all be addressed in the question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1> Backup all your data and keep win8 recovery disk handy.
2> boot into ubuntu live cd and do a simple os-prober in terminal
3> does it show win8? If yes, then follow this link             https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

else  there might be a risk factor. If u r not willing to risk your win8 partition, then simply delete the ubuntu partition from disk management to reclaim back your hard disk .space